# running code at exact times, a la crond/atd

Tags: c++, c, time

Suppose I'm implementing a clock, and I want to minmise the number of wakeups per unit time. So, I'd like to be woken up on full minutes only (when I need to update the display). What's the best way to do this (portably, preferably) in C (or C++)?

Comment: Most elegant, most portable, causing least wakeups. I'd be interested in solutions in all of these categories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++03 and C07 standards don't really provide any portable way to do this. If you can't depend on a newer compiler, nearly your only reasonably portable choice is probably POSIX threads (about which more below).

Under C++11, you can create a thread, and use `std::sleep_until`, or (if you prefer, for some reason) `std::sleep_for`. One reason to prefer the latter would be portability to C. C1x has a `thrd_sleep` function that's essentially similar to `std::sleep_for`, so it might be a little easier to use essentially the same function in both.

Portability (in this case) may be hard to define. These functions are in the C++ standard and C draft, but those are both obviously very new so it's hard to guess whether the compilers you care about actually implement them yet. At the same time, they're based fairly closely on pthreads, so there's probably a better chance of seeing them implemented already (or soon) than if they were mostly new and different.

If you're willing to restrict yourself to C++, you might also consider [Boost.thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread.html). It's pretty similar to what's going into the standard, but it's already available for nearly all the major compilers and platforms.

As mentioned above, another possibility would be to use POSIX threads directly. In theory that may not be quite as portable (at least in the long run), but in fact it's probably at least as portable right now -- and, in particular, may be portable to all the platforms you really care about, which is most of what really matters. Obviously they're available on essentially all Unix-like platforms, and there's also a [port to Win32](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/).

I should probably add a caveat that I'd guess is pretty minor: none of these really guarantees running at an "exact time". They pretty much guarantee that your thread will sleep for at least as long as you specify, but it could be longer -- but that's also true with `at` and `cron` as well. Most typical operating systems aren't "real time", so essentially any attempt at running at an exact time is hopeless, unless you define "exact" pretty loosely. Most people are primarily interested in being close enough that it looks and seems right to the user, so anything more accurate than a tenth of a second or so is unnecessary. In that case, you can generally do pretty well (though if the system is really heavily loaded, even that *could* be a problem).

Comment: I was hoping for an FD-based interface, so you could hook it up into the event loop of the GUI framework you're using, but I guess then I shouldn't have written "portable". I dislike using threads for the sole purpose of sleeping, but if it means portability, I guess I can overcome my dislike :) Thanks!